# Create a route that redirects users to a path via parameter

Tags: 8, routes

I'm working on a custom module that needs to act as a mediator between a third party service and this Drupal site to manipulate some parameters. I've created a route:

```
my_module.process_redirect:
  path: '/my_module/{action}/process/{path}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\RedirectController::process'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

Ideally, I'd like the destination route to be modified based on the value of `{action}`.

Is there any way to pass a path with slashes as a parameter? For intance:
`/my_module/abc/process/path/to/page'`
would result in `$action = 'abc'` and `$path = 'path/to/page`

Beyond replacing the slashes with another character and processing them in my controller I can't seem to find a way to make this work. This route will be user-facing so I'd like to keep it looking fairly clean if possible.

Thank you!

Comment: [This issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2741939) suggests Drupal still 'needs work' to handle route parameters with `/` in them.  Maybe your `process()` could do [func_get_args](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) and see what comes through and try and handle it yourself, seems sketchy though.

Comment: You can do this in path processing, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/225128/47547

Comment: Can you confirm you can't use slugs from your path?